# MATLAB: Generate all possible combination of a binary matrix with only one '1' in each column

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

MATLAB : I want to find out how to generate all possible combination of a matrix (N by M)  where:
- elements are "1" and "0".
- there should be only one "1" in each column.
- no limitation for rows.so multiple "1" is allowed within each row.

one possible state e.g. N=5 , M=6

```
1 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

furthermore I want to generate each possible combination matrix , then compute something  (e.g. a utility function in my problem) like this :

```
generate one possible matrix C
.
  .
    for i=1:N
      for j=1:M
        do something on C(:,:)
      end
    end
  .
.
```

(in the manner of exhaustive search)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be **lots**. Usually when a question here involves: *How do I generate all possible **X***, the real answer is: *Don't do it, there are too many possible **X**. Look for a different approach to your problem.*

Nevertheless, you could use the number representation in the base of your number of rows:

### Approach using: `dec2base`

Disclaimer: Due to limitations of `dec2base` this will only work for `2<=rows<=36` (Which is hopefully enough. Otherwise we would copy-edit the file `dec2base.m` and remove it's two last lines and the error check in line `24` to achieve arbitrary values of `2<=rows`. This code I won't post for copyright reasons.).

```
rows = 5; 
cols = 6;
assert((2<=rows)&&(rows<=36),'The dec2base-approach will only work for 2<=rows<=36');
symbols = dec2base(0:rows-1, rows, 1);
for ii = 0:rows^cols-1
    % Compute ii in base rows.
    iibR = dec2base(ii, rows, cols);
    C = bsxfun(@eq, symbols, iibR);
    disp(C);
end
```

### Generating the tuples without `dec2base`:

We could also generate these tuples that represent our numbers using `ndgrid`.

```
%%// Data
rows = 3;
cols = 4;
%%// Compute all k-tuples of numbers 1:n
n = rows;
k = cols;
Cs = cell(1,k);
[Cs{:}] = ndgrid(1:n);
tuples = reshape(cat(n+1, Cs{:}),n^k,[]);
%%// Compute matrices
for ii = 1:size(tuples,1);
    C = bsxfun(@eq, (1:rows).', tuples(ii,:));
    disp(C);
end
```

Comment: `dec2base` is a nice touch :)

Comment: Thanks! :) agree with you , but possibility here depends on number of "rows" and "cols", of course assuming a finite state considering small values for each one, gives answer finally whereas here we don't care about the complexity and running time , Since we're gonna exhaustively search through all possible states considering logical and finite inputs, in order to find the best answered state (optimal), then we could compare it with the outcome of our own approach. in my optimization problem the values are variable between 1 and 8 . Thanks again @knedlsepp

Comment: @knedlsepp There is a problem in the Code , for row>9 , run it for rows=12 and cols=5 for example , then display C when ii==10 , you will find out there is no '1' in last column, same result for remaining rows (e.g. ii==11 , so on). all columns should contains one '1'

Comment: @fhm: Thanks for spotting the error. This version should work now for `2<=rows<=36`. If you want more, you will have to copy-paste the contents of the `dec2base` via `edit dec2base`, delete the last two lines and the error-check in line 24 and save the function under a new name.

Comment: @knedlsepp , hope you are well,honestly as your answer was the best to help me, just want to ask you about two other forms of exhaustive search in that binary matrix where:  1) only one "1" is allowed in each row and no limitation for cols, and the other situation: 2) multiple "1" allowed in all rows and cols (at less one "1" should be in each col),  my email: foad.hajiaghajani [at] gmail.com . thanks for your help

Comment: @fhm: 1.) Tranpose this matrix. 2.) `for j = 0:2^(m*n), reshape(dec2bin(j,m*n),m,n)-'0', end`, which will probably take ages. I don't know from the top of my head how to limit the cols to include at least a 1. If you want to know more ask a SO question.

Comment: @fhm: Come on, at least give it some thought! It's basically there. You only need to define `n` and `m`.... *If you want to know more ask a SO question.*

Comment: @knedlsepp Thanks , (1) solved , and for (2) the state space is too large without limitation..well it seems, I have to ignore that limitation, and distinguish by using extra "if" control func :)